# Where to ask Linux general questions about HW stuff?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to understand how an Internet Box, based on Linux, is designed. It's 
made by a quite big operator in France; http://free.fr.

I'm sure I cannot post it to http://askubuntu.com, but which is an appropriate site to ask this question? Reverse Engineering?

Comment: "how is designed" is potentially a bit *too broad*, although it depends on your exact question, and what you mean by "an Internet Box".  Can you elaborate a little? You don't need to write out your entire question here, just explain in a sentence or two what you mean by "how is designed an internet box".

Comment: editted post///